# Array: What is the "s:" value in syntax based on?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

I need to do an import of an array of checkboxes, but there is a value that I don't how it is determined.

The array is based on a user meta option that I created that shows a list of category checkbox options. It grabs all of the categories and creates a checkbox option that can be saved to a user's profile. The categories have different levels (parent, child, or child-child).

This is part of the coding I used to create the user meta option:

```
$args = array( 'hide_empty' => 0, 'taxonomy'=> 'category');
$categories =  get_categories($args);

if ($categories){
                        foreach ( $categories as $category ){ 
                            if(in_array($category->term_id,(array)$data)) {
                                $selected = 'checked="checked""';
                            } else {
                                $selected = '';
                            }
                            echo '<input name="user_cats[]" value="'.$category->term_id.'" '.$selected.' type="checkbox"/> '.$category->name.'<br/>';
                        }
                    }
```

After doing a test save of the some of the checkbox options, I examined the database value of the "user_cats" field, it gives me something like this:

**a**:2:{**i**:0;**s**:2:"20";**i**:1;**s**:3:"343";}

Now, I know what all but one of the variables stand for.

**a** = Total amount (quantity) of values/selections

**i** = Sequential number of the value/selection (*Starting with 0)

**"X"** = The number value within the parenthesis is the value

My question is, what is the **s:** value based on? The reason I ask is because Im compiling a csv file of 1,300 records to import and I dont know how the **s:** values are determined. I tried just give s: a constant value of 2, but after importing the values the options were not selected based on the arrays that were imported. That didn't work.

So I have a feeling that the selecting of the correct options are based on the **s:** value. An alternative would be if Im able to import an array without that current syntax.

I spent a *long* time manually compiling the file with excel functions and tricks and this is the only road block. Any help with this would be a major savior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the php serialize format:

```
a:2 - array with 2 elements
s:2 - string 2 characters long
i:0 - integer with value "0"
```

Comment: I see! Now it makes a lot of since now. I wasn't sure what it was for. Thanks a mil! You saved me like a day of head aches, lol

Comment: For the most part, it's "type:size:value", though numbers don't have sizes, just type:value

Comment: Thats good to know. Im learning php and never really had to deal so much with arrays. Another nugget of knowledge in the bank. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

`s` stands for *string*.

`s:2:"20"` is a *string* of length 2 with a value of `20`.

This format is the result of [PHP serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

Answer (score 3):

`a:2:{i:0;s:2:"20";i:1;s:3:"343";}` is a serialized string.

You can call [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to reverse this.

```
var_dump(unserialize('a:2:{i:0;s:2:"20";i:1;s:3:"343";}');

#result
array
  0 => string '20' (length=2)
  1 => string '343' (length=3)
```

Therefore, you can break it up to the following:

```
a:2        - array of length 2.
i:0        - index 0
s:2:20     - string of length 2 value "20"
i:1        - index 1
s:3:343    - string of length 3 value "343"
```